# Trying to update ref on resize in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, responsive, user-experience

Having a bit of an issue.

So what I'm trying to achieve is having a ref on a viewport and using that value to calculate how many rows in a table to display at a time.
I've easily achieved actually grabbing the value: number. But I want this value to update on resize.
I thought that useLayoutEffect would help me to achieve this, but I was wrong.
I got it to work kind of by doing some weird useEffect thing, but it was an infinite loop, so I tossed that out.

Here is what I have so far. When I refresh the page the value is updated correctly, but I'm hoping for it to be a bit more responsive and not require a refresh to 're-math' the row count.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useLayoutEffect, createRef } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import TasksTable from 'components/Tables/TasksTable';
import Loader from 'components/Loader';
import { GetTasks } from 'api';

function ScheduledTasks() {
  const { account_id } = useParams();
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const [tasksLoaded, setTasksLoaded] = useState(false);

  **/* Begin Ref Attempt */**
  const [refHeight, setRefHeight] = useState(0);
  const viewHeight = createRef();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setRefHeight(viewHeight.current.offsetHeight);
  }, [viewHeight]);
 ** /* End Ref Attempt */**

  useEffect(() => {
    GetTasks(account_id)
      .then((data) => setTasks(data))
      .then(() => setTasksLoaded(true));
  }, [account_id]);

  return (
    <div className="accounts-container" ref={viewHeight}>
      {refHeight}
      {tasksLoaded ? <TasksTable tasks={tasks} /> : <Loader />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ScheduledTasks;
```

I've tried a useEffect, but this resulted in an infinite loop. I tried useRef and ended up with the same results and I've got right now.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this hook: https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/

```
// Hook
function useWindowSize() {
  // Initialize state with undefined width/height so server and client renders match
  // Learn more here: https://joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    // Handler to call on window resize
    function handleResize() {
      // Set window width/height to state
      setWindowSize({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      });
    }
    // Add event listener
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    // Call handler right away so state gets updated with initial window size
    handleResize();
    // Remove event listener on cleanup
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount
  return windowSize;
}
```